# How do I use gradle without internet access?

Tags: java, build, jenkins, gradle

I'm using gradle 1.6

We have been developing application with gradle but we found out that our internal jenkins has to go through proxy and that proxy is using NTLM which is really a pain for gradle. I tried everything on the internet with no luck. So, we would like to change to a backup plan to do everything local. We tried copying .gradle to the jenkins box but it could not find all the dependencies. What's the best way to migrate `.gradle` folder from one machine to another machine.

This is the command we use to build on our local machine

`gradle build --offline -g /tmp/lib`

It looks like everything is downloaded to that `/tmp/lib` folder then we moved that folder to the jenkins machine and use the same command to run. It still looks for dependences over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle dependency cache isn't guaranteed to be transferable between machines. Instead I'd focus on sorting out the NTLM issues (or lifting the restriction). You can get help at http://forums.gradle.org, or commercial support from http://gradleware.com.

Comment: We tried about the NILM and it could take months, but I will try forums.gradle.org thanks.